# Strange behaviour of gdb

Tags: c++, pointers, char, gdb

I am debugging following sample code in gdb

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void c (char** q)
{
    q = new char*[2];
    if (q == NULL)
        cout<<"NO OK";
    else
        cout<<"OK";
}

int main ()
{
    char** d = NULL;
    c(d);
    return 1;
}
```

Now this program gives output as "OK"
but while debugging this code in gdb i found following behavior
gdb -version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5.1

```
Breakpoint 1, c (q=0x0) at issue.cpp:8
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
8           q = new char*[2];
(gdb) p q
$1 = (char **) 0x0
(gdb) n
9           if (q == NULL)
(gdb) p q
$2 = (char **) 0x0
(gdb) p q==0
$3 = true
(gdb) n
12              cout<<"OK";
(gdb) p q
$4 = (char **) 0x0
(gdb) p q==0
$5 = true
(gdb)
```

gdb is showing q value a null but code is executing differently.

Answer (score 2):

Well: `warning: Source file is more recent than executable.` - That may be your answer. Try recompiling your code.

Comment: No. 
Breakpoint 1, c (q=0x0) at issue.cpp:8
8           q = new char*[2];
(gdb) p q
$1 = (char **) 0x0
(gdb) n
9           if (q == NULL)
(gdb) p q
$2 = (char **) 0x0
(gdb)

Comment: Did that. Same behavior.

Comment: Do you understand why you are getting that warning? Are you absolutely sure it is spurious?

Comment: Yes. I have opened source file and again saved it after building the executable. Can you please try at your end.

Comment: Ok. Tested it ... I posted a new answer, since I managed to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something going on that messes up with the gdb logic. I am encountering your described behavior in `gcc` 4.8.3 running in `cygwin` (32 bits).

I am getting this output in my gdb session for your code:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:21
21          char** d = NULL;
(gdb) s
22          c(d);
(gdb) s
c (q=0x0) at test.cpp:9
9           q = new char*[2];
(gdb) s
13          if (q == NULL)
(gdb) p q
$1 = (char **) 0x0
(gdb) p &q
$2 = (char ***) 0x22abd0
(gdb) x 0x22abd0
0x22abd0:       0x00000000
```

Now if I simply change your function like this:

```
void c (char** q)
{
    cout << q << endl;
    q = new char*[2];
    if (q == NULL)
        cout<<"NO OK";
    else
        cout<<"OK";
}
```

gdb seems now capable of getting that q parameter's value:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:21
21          char** d = NULL;
(gdb) s
22          c(d);
(gdb) s
c (q=0x0) at test.cpp:8
8           cout << q << endl;
(gdb) s
0
9           q = new char*[2];
(gdb) s
13          if (q == NULL)
(gdb) p q
$1 = (char **) 0x2004a0a8
(gdb) p &q
$2 = (char ***) 0x22abd0
(gdb) x 0x22abd0
0x22abd0:       0x2004a0a8
```

Let's change the code like this:

```
void c (char** q)
{
    q = new char*[2];
    cout << q << endl;
    if (q == NULL)
        cout<<"NO OK";
    else
        cout<<"OK";
}
```

The generated code for this function looks something like this: (compiled -g -ggdb -O0)

```
.cfi_startproc
pushl   %ebp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
.cfi_offset 5, -8
movl    %esp, %ebp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 5
subl    $40, %esp
movl    $8, (%esp)
call    __Znaj
movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
movl    $__ZSt4cout, (%esp)
call    __ZNSolsEPKv
movl    $__ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_, 4(%esp)
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    __ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
cmpl    $0, -12(%ebp)
jne L2
movl    $LC0, 4(%esp)
movl    $__ZSt4cout, (%esp)
call    __ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
jmp L1
```

Now it seems from this code that the compiler uses for `if (q == NULL)` the value at `$ebp - 12`. Let's see how this goes during the `gdb` session:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:19
19          char** d = NULL;
(gdb) s
20          c(d);
(gdb) s
c (q=0x0) at test.cpp:8
8           q = new char*[2];
(gdb) s
9           cout << q << endl;
(gdb) s
0x2003a078
11          if (q == NULL)
(gdb) p q
$1 = (char **) 0x0
(gdb) p &q
$2 = (char ***) 0x22abd0
(gdb) p $ebp
$3 = (void *) 0x22abc8
(gdb) p $ebp - 12
$4 = (void *) 0x22abbc
(gdb) x 0x22abbc
0x22abbc:       0x2003a078
```

Looks like `gdb` looks for q at a different address than the one it actually is at. You probably just got yourself into a delicate `gcc` - `gdb` interaction issue.

Answer (score 0):

Normally debugging is done on the *non-optimized executable* (and measuring performance - on optimized executable). This is because doing things fast and doing them exactly the way want them to do is mutually exclusive.

Your `c` function can be rewritten to

```
void c (char** q)
{
    cout<<"OK";
}
```

This is because you assign the `new`ed array on the function argument, that is, the local variable. This means the code has no side effects to the rest of the world. Also, `new` never returns `NULL`, and so `q == 0` is always `false`.

EDIT: Ok, it's actually more complicated than a simple debug/release difference. Since the actual problem lies elsewhere, to make this answer more useful, this is how it should behave (code compiled with `g++ 4.9.0`, and `gdb` version is `7.7`)

Non-optimized `g++ -g`

```
Breakpoint 1, c (q=0x0) at a.cpp:8
8           q = new char*[2];
(gdb) p q
$1 = (char **) 0x0
(gdb) n
9           if (q == NULL)
(gdb) p q
$2 = (char **) 0x611290
(gdb) p q==0
$3 = false
(gdb) n
12              cout<<"OK";
(gdb) p q
$4 = (char **) 0x611290
(gdb) p q==0
$5 = false
```

Optimized `g++ -g -O2`

```
Breakpoint 1, c (q=0x0) at a.cpp:8
8           q = new char*[2];
(gdb) p q
$1 = (char **) 0x0
(gdb) n
12              cout<<"OK";
(gdb) p q
$2 = <optimized out>
(gdb)
```

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with weather or not you enable optimizations. Even with `-O0` it's still happening.